# What is the minimum number of written bytes of a SocketChannel when its key is writable?

Tags: java, nonblocking, socketchannel, java-nio

Let's say we're going to write some bytes to a `SocketChannel` within a writable `SelectionKey`.

```java
// in a single selection loop

if (selectedKey.isWritable()) {

    final var channel = (SocketChannel) selectedKey.channel();
    assert !channel.isBlocking(); // checked!

    final var buffer = (ByteBuffer) selectedKey.attachment();
    assert buffer.hasRemaining(); // checked!

    final var w = channel.write(buffer);
    assert w >= 0; // ok, no harm
    assert w >  0; // really?
}
```

My question is,

- when a `SelectionKey` is *writable*
- and the `buffer` has *remaining*,

Can I ***technically be assured*** that the result of the `channel.write(buffer)` is ***always positive***?

In a same point of view, is the underlying socket's output buffer ***always has a free space* when the `selectedKey.isWritable()` results `true`**?

P.S. I already check the documentation.

> Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or possibly none at all. A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for example, cannot write any more bytes than are free in the socket's output buffer.

Comment: I believe that the write is *queued*, and the number of bytes in `w` represents the number of bytes queued to write. What problem are you trying to to solve?

Comment: @ijustlovemath, it depends on what you mean by "queued".  I/O is usually *buffered* by the system, and that's what this question is about, but "queued" is a somewhat unconventional way of describing that.

Comment: The non-blocking check is pointless here. You can’t select on a blocking mode channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I ***technically be assured*** that the result of the `channel.write(buffer)` is ***always positive***?

**TL;DR**: as the question is posed, no, there is no such *assurance*.

The general model of operation for non-blocking channel I/O is that when an I/O operation is requested, as many bytes are transferred as can be done without blocking, up to a maximum of the number requested.  That may be 0 bytes.  Under the conditions you describe, that would normally be a positive number of bytes, but

- If there is another thread that could attempt to write to the channel then between when the channel is selected for writability and when the thread you are focusing on attempts to write, the other thread could transfer enough bytes to the channel that it is no longer writable without blocking.  In that case, the `write()` you are focusing on could return 0.
- There are various conditions in which the `write()` could throw an exception instead of returning anything at all.
- Even if neither of the above applies, Java simply does not provide a guarantee that you will see a positive number of bytes written in such a case, only that the attempt will not block.  The write is highly likely to return a positive result if neither of the above points applies, and there may be platforms where you can safely rely on that, but Java does not *assure* it.  Robust code should be prepared for the possibility that the `write()` returns 0.

---

> In a same point of view, is the underlying socket's output buffer ***always has a free space* when the `selectedKey.isWritable()` results `true`**?

A channel's selection key indicating that the channel is writable means that at least one byte can be transferred to it without blocking.  There is only indirect attestation to there being an underlying output buffer at all, though in practice, that is indeed how all socket implementations I know work.  Supposing that there is indeed an output buffer, yes, the channel being writable means there is at least one byte of space available in that buffer.

Comment: Also, I think that checking that the channel is ready for bytes before writing them is considered an anti pattern, as there's a race condition there (it could fill between the check and the write). It's better practice to just do the thing you want to do, and handle the exceptions as they occur.

Comment: Agreed, @ijustlovemath.  In this case it's a bit grey, however. Assertions are for documenting and validating *program invariants*.  Under circumstances where the conditions the OP is asserting really are invariants, it does no harm to perform those checks.  And of course, they won't be performed anyway if the class is compiled without assertions enabled.